# Populate dropdown menu dynamically with flask

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dmenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Select Thing
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dmenu">
                {% for thing in master.things %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ thing.thing_name }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

`master` and `things` are getting imported correctly because I can loop through and print them. Only when I try to create the dropdown-items with the loop it doesn't work. I get an empty list.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to be more specific I'm afraid. What do you mean by "doesn't work" - do you have an empty list? Where is your view function?

Comment: @roganjosh Yep, empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a python problem, it is about using `bootstrap`.

If you are using bootstrap, you need to add the following javascript code in you page to enable the dropdown behavior:

```js
<script>
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
```

Also, you need to include bootstrap dependencies, inluding `jquery` and `popperjs` I believe.

From their page: [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```